# Scraping dynamic website by Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I try to scrape dynamic website by BS4 python:

https://www.nadlan.gov.il/?search=%D7%AA%D7%9C%20%D7%90%D7%91%D7%99%D7%91%20%20%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%95

I tried:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = urlopen(wiki)
soup = BeautifulSoup("https://www.nadlan.gov.il/?search=תל אביב יפו")
```

I have 2 problems:

1. The website is dynamic, when I view the page source, I don't see the page content only JavaScript scripts:

   ```
   <script>
       document.write("<script src='scripts/dis/bundleJS.js?v=" + globalAppVersion + "'><\/script>")
       document.write("<script id='srcGovmap' src='https://new.govmap.gov.il/govmap/api/govmap.api.js?v='" + globalAppVersion + "'><\/script>")
       document.write("<script src='MainLoader.js?v=" + globalAppVersion + "'><\/script>")
       document.write("<script id='tld-search-srcipt' 
   src='https://www.nadlan.gov.il/TldSearch/Scripts/ac.js?v=" + globalAppVersion + "'><\/script>");
   </script>

   <script src="scripts/dis/accessibility/b1.js?v=3" type="text/javascript"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">

   accessibility_rtl = true;
   pixel_from_side = 20;
   pixel_from_start = 15;

   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#accessibility_icon').attr('src', 'images/accessibility_icon.png')
       $('.accessibility_div_wrap>.btn_accessibility > span.accessibility_component').html('')
   });
   ```
2. When I open the site it takes a few seconds for the data to load:

[image]

How can I solve these problems by Selenium?

Comment: If you want to scrap a dynamic website you should use Selenium not BS4

Comment: or scrapy-splash but best w'd be to use a js framework  Puppeteer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is loaded dynamically via JavaScript. You can simulate the Ajax calls with `requests`/`json` modules. For example:

```
import json
import requests


url = 'https://www.nadlan.gov.il/Nadlan.REST/Main/GetAssestAndDeals'
data = {"MoreAssestsType":0,"FillterRoomNum":0,"GridDisplayType":0,"ResultLable":"תל אביב -יפו","ResultType":1,"ObjectID":"5000","ObjectIDType":"text","ObjectKey":"UNIQ_ID","DescLayerID":"SETL_MID_POINT","Alert":None,"X":180428.31832654,"Y":665726.5550939,"Gush":"","Parcel":"","showLotParcel":False,"showLotAddress":False,"OriginalSearchString":"תל אביב  יפו","MutipuleResults":False,"ResultsOptions":None,"CurrentLavel":2,"Navs":[{"text":"מחוז תל אביב - יפו","url":None,"order":1}],"QueryMapParams":{"QueryToRun":None,"QueryObjectID":"5000","QueryObjectType":"number","QueryObjectKey":"SETL_CODE","QueryDescLayerID":"KSHTANN_SETL_AREA","SpacialWhereClause":None},"isHistorical":False,"PageNo":1,"OrderByFilled":"DEALDATETIME","OrderByDescending":True,"Distance":0}
result = requests.post(url, json=data).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(result, indent=4))

# print all results to screen:
for r in result['AllResults']:
    for k, v in r.items():
        print('{:<30} {}'.format(k, v))
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
DEALDATE                       12.12.2020
DEALDATETIME                   2020-12-12T00:00:00
FULLADRESS                     
DISPLAYADRESS                  
GUSH                           7104-289-264
DEALNATUREDESCRIPTION          דירה
ASSETROOMNUM                   3
FLOORNO                        None
DEALNATURE                     90
DEALAMOUNT                     3,650,000
NEWPROJECTTEXT                 1
PROJECTNAME                    מגדלי גינדי תל אביב
BUILDINGYEAR                   None
YEARBUILT                      
BUILDINGFLOORS                 None
KEYVALUE                       10812534855
TYPE                           2
POLYGON_ID                     7104-289
TREND_IS_NEGATIVE              False
TREND_FORMAT                   
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DEALDATE                       31.07.2020
DEALDATETIME                   2020-07-31T00:00:00
FULLADRESS                     עגנון ש"י 28, תל אביב -יפו
DISPLAYADRESS                  עגנון ש"י 28
GUSH                           6634-336-33
DEALNATUREDESCRIPTION          דירה
ASSETROOMNUM                   5
FLOORNO                        None
DEALNATURE                     130
DEALAMOUNT                     6,363,000
NEWPROJECTTEXT                 1
PROJECTNAME                    הפילהרמונית
BUILDINGYEAR                   2020
YEARBUILT                      
BUILDINGFLOORS                 9
KEYVALUE                       10812534851
TYPE                           1
POLYGON_ID                     6634-336
TREND_IS_NEGATIVE              False
TREND_FORMAT                   
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


...and so on.
```

Comment: Thank you, How can I load more data by scroll down the page?

Comment: @ronkolel Increase the `"PageNo"` key in `data` to `2`, `3`, ... to load more results.